# Black screen after installing Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I downloaded Ubuntu 11.10 one week ago and burned it to a CD. I installed it on my system which has a 1.5 TB hard.

It installed successfully and I clicked on the restart button. The computer restarted and I chose the first option, which was to load Ubuntu. A black screen would appear with a cursor in top left hand side and I think the system was hung. I repeated this process by erasing the last Ubuntu install but I faced a similar problem.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this: [Black screen on boot](http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/ubuntu-11-04-blank-screen-on-boot-solved/)

It might work for you! Good luck.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.